# How to return WebRequest Multidimensional JSON?

Tags: c#, json, http

this is my current code:

```
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        HttpRequestCachePolicy policy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.Default);
        HttpWebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = policy;
        HttpRequestCachePolicy noCachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("some URl that returns a json");
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
        request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;
        request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.CachePolicy = noCachePolicy;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        return // RESPONSE AS JSON???;
    }

    public class Persons
    {
        public string index { get; set; }
        public string thing { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to return the response as multidimensional json..

How can i do that? 
It should look like this:

```
{"data":{"Person1":{"id":1,"thing":"thingOne","name":"personOneName","title":"personOneTitle"},"Person2":{"id":2,"thing":"thingTwo","name":"personTwoName","title":"personTwoTitle"}}
```

Comment: Multidimensional? It looks like an object with "data" that is an array of `Person` although not in valid JSON. You could just return the serialized collection of `Person` and ditch the "data" field or make wrapper class with a "data" field.

Comment: maybe i talk about something else.. so at the end the json has to look like this
{"data":{"Person1":{"id":1,"thing":"thingOne","name":"personOneName","title":"personOneTitle"},"Person2":{"id":2,"thing":"thingTwo","name":"personTwoName","title":"personTwoTitle"}}, "type":"Person","version":"1.1.0"}

the response of the httprequest gives undefined mount of persons and i need to return them as valid json for javascript and i dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to add the directive below to your class

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

This code will turn your response into an object.

```
Stream newStream = response .GetResponseStream();
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(newStream);    
var result = sr.ReadToEnd();    

//this will turn your response into a c# object of RootObject Type
//only do this is you're sure it will Deserialize into a RootObject type. 
var convertResponseToObj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result); 

//if you want to see what's being returned by your endpoint 
//without turning it into a RootObject type then remove <RootObject> see line below.
//doing this may help you Deserialize the response correctly. 

//var convertResponseToObj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result); 

public class Persons
{
     public string index { get; set; }
     public string thing { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
     public string title { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
     public List<Person> data {get; set;}
}
```

If you want to do some manipulations to that c# object and then turn it into JSON you can can do this:

```
string myJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(someCSharpObj); //this will turn your c# object into json
```